# Unknown 3-dots button removal from the top bar of GNOME Shell

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, activities-overview

The upper-left corner, the 3-dots button arrange windows, but I'd like to remove it. What's the name and its configuration panel?
[image]

Info:
/usr/bin/dbus-run-session
/usr/bin/gnome-session
/usr/bin/gnome-session-custom-session

Comment: What is ur Ubuntu version? What is the gnome-shell theme you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably using Arc (or one of its derivatives) as your GNOME Shell theme.

Arc theme changes the '*Activities*' button at the top-left corner to this three-dots button. In a Ubuntu installation without any modifications you would see the word 'Activities' instead.

You may use the [**Activities Configurator**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/) GNOME Shell extension to remove or modify this button.

[image]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

Refer to this to learn more about installing and configuring GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481)